# Magento SOAP calls and filters on Assigned Products

Tags: php, web-services, magento, soap

i've been trying to add filters for Visibility =4 , status= 1 and qty > 0 on the magento soap calls at my backend. but with no luck here is my line :

```
$products = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts' , $catId ) ;
```

here is what i've tried :

```
$filters = array('status' => 1 , 'visibility' => 4  , 'qty' => array( '>' => 0 ) ) ; 
$products = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts' , $catId , $filters) ;
```

and this :

```
$filters = array( $catId ,'status' => 1 , 'visibility' => 4  , 'qty' => array( '>' => 0 ) ); 
$products = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts' , $filters ) ;
```

but none of the above worked for me i get soap errors in response.

Can anyone guid me to the proper why on adding filters.

I couldn't find any examples on how to add filters to this one, if any one of you have a source where i can find how to add filters to the different soap calls with magento i would appreciated it a lot.

**EDIT** 
if someone have the same problem as me, just stop looking for a solution in SOAP and USE Magento API as the following :

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status',1)
                ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility',array('in' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use filters in the assignedProducts service. This service is very limited and accepts only one parameter and that is Category ID. If you want to filter Category products then you can use catalog.productList service and filter by category_ids field and the other fields you want to filter by.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.list.html

Comment: can you please explain how to add category_ids to the filter on catalog_product.list i can't get it to work , the other filters works great but category_ids doesn't

Comment: Sorry, it seems, since Magento 1.4 category_ids is no longer available to the  product list and filter will not work. When I had similar problem, I ended up extending Magento API and adding my filters to the collection that will be returned by the service. Also filtering by qty will not work in product list, as qty must be requested separately with "cataloginventory_stock_item.list".

Comment: Yes exactly thank you for your help i ended up using Magento API too it's much more flexible and have all the filters i need. SOAP unfortunately can't do the trick here